# Concrete Mathematics: Sum of on or above main diagonal of an array (deriving equation 2.33)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

I would like to check my understanding of an Iversonian equation presented shortly before 2.33 (page 37 in paper book) of Concrete Mathematics (Graham, Knuth, Patashnik).  They discuss deriving a simple formula for finding the sum of all elements on or above the main diagonal of an array. The book says:

> Our goal is to find a simple formula for

$$
S_◹ = \sum_{1 \le j \le k \le n} a_ja_k
$$

I get that part however I am unsure of the Iversonian equation:

$$
[1 \le j \le k \le n] + [1 \le k \le j \le n] = [1 \le j,k \le n] + [1 \le j=k \le n]
$$

Why is it not simply:

$$
[1 \le j \le k \le n] + [1 \le k \le j \le n] = [1 \le j,k \le n]
$$

I *think* this is because, in the process of doing the LHS $[1 \le j \le k \le n] + [1 \le k \le j \le n]$ we count the diagonal twice. Hence adding it on again on the RHS of that Iversonian equation.

Comment: This question has arisen a few times on MSE; you might try looking at a [site-specific google](https://www.google.com/search?q=iversonian+equation+diagonal+site:math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thank you, I will review that and use the site-specific Google search in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. We have
\begin{align*}
&\color{blue}{[1 \le j \le k \le n] + [1 \le k \le j \le n] }\\
&\qquad=\left([1 \le j < k \le n] +[1 \le j = k \le n]\right)\\
&\qquad\qquad + \left([1 \le k < j \le n] + [1 \le k = j \le n]\right)\\
&\qquad=\left([1 \le j < k \le n] +[1 \le j = k \le n] + [1 \le k < j \le n] \right)\\
&\qquad\qquad + [1 \le k = j \le n]\\
&\qquad\color{blue}{=[1 \le j, k \le n]+[1 \le j = k \le n]}
\end{align*}
according to the claim.